# Entity Framework 4 Unit Testing and Mocking

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-4, nunit, repository-pattern

I am very new to unit testing when it comes to databases and especially entity framework and I am now stuck. I am using NUnit to test and mock the entities used and am working using a generic repository. My entity framework has a full set of POCO classes and the bit I am currently testing looks like this:

```
    campaignRepoMock = new DynamicMock(typeof(IRepository<Campaign>));
    campaignRepoMock.ExpectAndReturn("First", testCampaign, new Func<Campaign, bool>(c => c.CampaignID == testCampaign.CampaignID));
    CampaignService campaignService = new CampaignService((IRepository<Campaign>)campaignRepoMock.MockInstance);
    Campaign campaign = campaignService.GetCampaign(testCampaign.Key, ProjectId);
    Assert.AreEqual(testCampaign, campaign);
```

testCampaign is a single POCO campaign test object. The method "First" in the IRepository looks like the following:

```
    public T First(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.FirstOrDefault<T>(predicate);
    }
```

The error I am getting from Nunit is

```
CampaignServiceTests.Campaign_Get_Campaign:   
  Expected: <System.Func`2[Campaign,System.Boolean]>  
  But was: <System.Func`2[Campaign,System.Boolean]>
```

So it is basically saying that it is getting what it is expecting, but its throwing an error? Maybe my understanding of this is all wrong, I just want to test the searching for a Campaign based on its key and the project it is linked to. The GetCampaigns method just search the repository sent to it for a campaign that has both of those items.

Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code, over here

```
campaignRepoMock.ExpectAndReturn("First", testCampaign, new Func<Campaign, bool>(c => c.CampaignID == testCampaign.CampaignID));
```

you are setting up your mock object to return a function that is not identical to your testCampaign.

`Assert.AreEqual()` tests for strict equality. `testCampaign` and `campaign` are of the same type and have the same content, but refer to different objects.

What mocking framework are you using? Looks pretty complicated and confusing to me. For starting I would recommend something like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I shall look into that and get back to you. I am using the NUnit.Mocks mocking framework. I looked at Moq but couldnt get my head around it as easily as this, maybe i should give it another go.

Comment: Once you get it, it's really easy. Have a look at this introduction to Moq: http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/8

Comment: Thanks Dennis, also found a good post on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769414/cannot-seem-to-moq-ef-codefirst-4-1-help-anyone. Turns out searching for "EF" bring more results than "Entity Framework". Will use Moq instead.